# Date format - Meta Box plugin

Tags: plugins, metabox, post-meta

I am getting a date using the plugin [Meta Box](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/).

The output is: "**2014-10-30**" and i'd like: "**30/oct/2014**"

There is a way to change the default format?

This is the register of the metabox:

```
$prefix = 'ns_';

'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name'  => 'Evento',
                'id'    => $prefix . 'event_date',
                'type'  => 'date',
            ),
```

And i'm calling it this way:

```
<?php echo rwmb_meta( 'ns_event_date' ); ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably but this would be using a PHP function along the lines of,

```
$metadate = rwmb_meta( 'ns_event_date' );
$date = new DateTime($metadate);
echo $date->format('d-M-Y');
```